# Place Responsive button inside a TextArea

Tags: html, css, angular

I developed a text area that allows me to associate people. My problem is placing the responsive button (always in the bottom right) and making the text not "pass" over it.

Can anyone help me?

**[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/mentions-devextreme-html-editor-6jgc1)**

**css**

```
.Sendbtn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
   margin-right: 21px;
  margin-top: -76px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <dx-html-editor>
    <dxi-mention
      valueExpr="text"
      displayExpr="text"
      [dataSource]="employees"
    ></dxi-mention>
  </dx-html-editor>
  <img
    class="img-responsive Sendbtn"
    src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/search-png/search-icon-clip-art-clkerm-vector-clip-art-online-0.png" alt=""/>
```

**Problem**

The text passes over the button :(

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dig down into the dx-html-editor element you can find the `<p>` element that contains the text. If you give this a `margin-right` the text will stop running over the button.

```
.dx-htmleditor .ql-container .ql-editor p {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

You might need to play around with the exact selectors to get it perfectly right but that should be step in the right direction.

Comment: I don't know why but it's not working as it should :(

Comment: Can you achieve the effect using the developer tools to alter the CSS? If yes, then it is just a matter of getting the CSS in the stylesheet right. You may need to add more selectors to correctly target it.